# Office Interop open xlsx file on a client with Excel 2003

Tags: c#, excel

Is there a way to open an xlsx file with Microsoft Office interop on a user machine with excel 2003 installed.

or

can I access/run the Microsoft Compatipility Pack converter from c#

My program generates xlsx files with gembox. The xlsx files contain pictures so gembox cannot save the xls correctly (with pictures).

Wenn I open the xlsx with the converter on an excel 2003 machine it opens correctla and I can save the file as xls that still shows the pictures.

I tryed the following without success:

```
     String _xlsx="myXLSXFile.xlsx";
     String _xls="myXLSFile.xls";
     Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                    Excel._Workbook oBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(_xlsx);
                    excelApp.Visible = true;
                    oBook.SaveAs(_xls);
```

Comment: If Excel can open the file, you won't have any problems opening it through interop. If it does, you need to add the pack but won't need to change the code. Why are you trying to convert XLSX to a deprecated format that is no longer supported by Google Docs and *requires* an Excel installation to read?

Comment: excel 2003 cannot open it only with the Compatipility pack which is called when you open the xlsx file but not when you open it with interop!!! I develop for customers with different excel versions on different machines.

Comment: 2003 is 13 years old. I wouldn't know where to find a copy to test at this point (MSDN subscription maybe)? And as I said, xls is deprecated. The reason Google doesn't support it any more is that it *does* need Excel on the server, to process or create. `xlsx` doesn't. A library like EPPlus can read and create `xlsx` files directly. That's a huge improvement in scalability and memory usage. Why don't you simply create the xlsx files and let the clients install the Compatibility package?

Comment: that is exactly what i Do. I create the xlsx and those who have excel 11 or higher can open with excel auomatization. But it seems that you cannot immagine how many Excel 2003 are still productive!!!

Comment: I don't have to imagine how many people drive 30 year old cars either. I either charge them extra (that's what Google does) or simply avoid them. If they can't afford to buy even a 7-year old version, they probably will delay payments as well. What I don't understand is why *you* are using Excel 2003. Why don't you use a newer version to convert the files? All versions can *save* to `xls`

Comment: BTW perhaps you should check NPOI to create `xls` files withoug using Excel

Comment: I found the solution now on an old Computer with excel 2003 installed. After updating to office sp3 everything runs like expected. I can open the xlsx and save as xls by office interop. It is hard to test without equivalent (old) environment.

Comment: there are also customers having own customers with even older enivironment who ask for excel files. And I can tell you that the biggest german Insurance also still works with excel 2003 and you can be sure they will pay their invoices.

Comment: The current latest version of GemBox.Spreadsheet supports pictures in older XLS format, see [Supported File Formats](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/Supported_File_Formats.htm) help page.